# Plotting an image (ggplot2) with decreasing order from the central zone for 2 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot like the following:
[image: PLot]

But I have no idea about to merge 2 plots from 2 different database,

```
`p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x , y)) + geom_point( size=3, color="black") + geom_segment(aes(xend=x, yend=0))


p2 <- ggplot(data = df2, aes( x, y)) + geom_point( size=3, color="black") + geom_segment(aes(xend=x, yend=0))`
```

And how can I add the central segment with "total costs"
**I have tried to use the simplest possible code to make it easier to understand.**
Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making two separate plots and glueing them together I would suggest to make one plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Example data
df <- mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer %in% c("audi", "volkswagen")) %>%
  mutate(model = glue::glue("{model} ({year})")) %>%
  distinct(model, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  top_n(5, hwy) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(manufacturer, x = model, y = hwy)
df <- split(df, df$manufacturer)

# Arrange datasets
df$audi <- arrange(df$audi, y)
df$volkswagen <- arrange(df$volkswagen, desc(y))

# Glue datasets together and add one row in between to make space  for the axis
df_axis <- df$audi %>%
  add_row(manufacturer = "axis", x = "", y = NA) %>%
  bind_rows(df$volkswagen) %>%
  # Set the order of the x axis categories
  mutate(x = forcats::fct_inorder(x))

# Helper
axis <- factor("", levels = levels(df_axis$x))
maxy <- 50
expand_axis_y = 1.1
breaks_y <- seq(0, maxy, 10)

ggplot(data = df_axis, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, color = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, yend = 0)) +
  geom_segment(
    data = data.frame(
      x = axis, yend = expand_axis_y * maxy
    ),
    aes(xend = x, y = 0, yend = yend),
    color = "black", arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches"))
  ) +
  # ggtext::geom_richtext is much more flexible than the default geom_text or _label
  ggtext::geom_richtext(
    data = data.frame(
      x = axis,
      y = breaks_y
    ),
    aes(label = scales::number(y), x = x, y = y),
    color = "black" , vjust = .55, fill = "white", label.colour = NA) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.025,0.001))) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL)
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to combine data sets into a single one that is plotted - here's how it could work:

```
library(tidyverse)

## suppose you have these two data frames
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = rnorm(20))
df2 <- data.frame(x = -20:-1, y = rnorm(20))

## add a parameter to distinguish both datasets
df <- df %>%
    mutate(source = "a") %>%
    add_row(x = 0, y = 1.1, source = "c") ## add a row holding the data for the central value

df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(source = "b")

## bind data frames into onw:
p_df <- rbind(df, df2)

## plot
ggplot(p_df, aes(x, y, ymax = y, ymin = 0, colour = source)) + 
    geom_pointrange()
```